# Как сделать ul в ряд, где li идет под li?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Всем привет. Возможно все довольно просто, но мучаюсь, как сделать так, чтобы было как на изображении?

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

[image: Вот так, чтобы они друг за другом были, при этом в ряд.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете использовать masonry.js, если хотите получить плиточную верстку, либо [плитку на css](http://www.magisters.org/community/8/62), но она работает как блоки в газетах - снизу-вверх слева-направо. Либо прописать для каждого `ul > li:nth-child(<номер>)` стиль css

```css
    ul {
        width: 800px;
        height: 600px;

        -webkit-column-count: 3;
        -moz-column-count: 3;
        column-count: 3;
    }

    ul li {
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 5px;
        width: 100%;

        text-align: center;
    }

    ul li:before {
        content: '</li>';
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 50px;
        color: gray;
    }

    ul li:nth-child(1) {
        height: calc(100% - 10px); /* calc(size - 10px) нужен из-за указанных magin 5px (сверху и снизу) */
    }
    ul li:nth-child(2) {
        height: calc(30% - 10px);
    }
    ul li:nth-child(3) {
        height: calc(70% - 10px);
    }
    ul li:nth-child(4) {
        height: calc(50% - 10px);
    }
    ul li:nth-child(5) {
        height: calc(50% - 10px);
    }
```

```html
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Что нужно для каждого li прописать? Этот вариант подходит, но не знаю что за стиль. Плитка на ксс, там по ссылке все на div, мне важно именно ul-li

Comment: я обновил ответ, если вам не пришло сообщение

Answer (score 2):

Вариант похож с предыдущим ответом, только подход немного другой к gaps:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

ul {
  display: block;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
          column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-gap: 1rem;
          column-gap: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
ul li {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
  background-color: black;
  border-bottom: 1rem solid white;
}
ul li:nth-of-type(1) {
  height: 100%;
}
ul li:nth-of-type(2) {
  height: 40%;
}
ul li:nth-of-type(3) {
  height: 60%;
}
ul li:nth-of-type(4) {
  height: 60%;
}
ul li:nth-of-type(5) {
  height: 40%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: кстати, да, забыл про flex. вероятно, он тут будет лучше